# Rails: Creating different types of posts using STI (Single Table Inheritance)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs, sti

I am currently designing Craigslist-like "rails" web application for my own project.

The application should allow users create a posting wherever they'd like to such as for sales, job, rentals and etc.

First thing I did was to create a class Post and wanted children-type of posts like post-in-rental or post-in-sales.

Would I get recommendation whether STI (Single Table Inheritance) is useful in this design or should I create many single models?

These are my concerns:

1. each section of posts(rent or buysell) has its own view and many different attributes
2. in the future, I might add more purposes.

Thank you for your opinion !

Comment: Well - my blog has categories - and i built a category table so that I could easily change the category name or add categories - I wouldn't use STI unless you really think it adds a performance addition - i'd maintain the model flexibility going forward - and I expect your question will get flagged because they don't like opinion questions here :)

Comment: @MageeWorld Thank you. It doesn't seem to have any problem yet with single models design. I guess STI's more suitable in comments model which may belong to various Posting models.